# Datediff function in TeraData SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata, date-arithmetic

i'm new here and it's all a bit confusing, so i'm gonna excuse myself in the beginning, if i do something wrong here.

I usually used MySQL or sometimes Oracle but now I have to switch to Teradata.

Simply i need to convert this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(),`startdate`)/365.25) AS `years`, 
       COUNT(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(),`startdate`)/365.25)) AS `numberofemployees` 
FROM `employees` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY `years` 
ORDER BY `years`;
```

into teradata.

Would be great if someone could help :)

Comment: Teradata: simply subtract dates: SELECT DATE 'date1' - DATE 'date2';

Comment: This is an approximate age calculation, `(current_date - startdate)/365.25`, exact age calculation: `Cast((Months_Between(Current_Date, startdate) / 12) AS smallint)`

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent of your query in Teradata would be :

```
SELECT FLOOR((CURRENT_DATE - startdate)/365.2500) AS years, 
       COUNT(FLOOR((CURRENT_DATE - startdate )/365.2500)) AS numberofemployees 
FROM employees
--WHERE 1
GROUP BY years 
ORDER BY years;
```

CURRENT_DATE is equivalent to NOW() (without the time part, part DATEDIFF would have ignored it, anyway).
In Teradata you can simply subtract dates to get days in between.
Also, I added two zeroes at the end of 365.25 to force Teradata to evaluate the division to 4 decimal places, because MySQL seems to perform it that way ([https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#:~:text=In%20division%20performed%20with%20/%2C%20the%20scale%20of%20the%20result%20when%20using%20two%20exact-value%20operands%20is%20the%20scale%20of%20the%20first%20operand%20plus%20the%20value%20of%20the%20div_precision_increment%20system%20variable%20(which%20is%204%20by%20default)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#:%7E:text=In%20division%20performed%20with%20/%2C%20the%20scale%20of%20the%20result%20when%20using%20two%20exact-value%20operands%20is%20the%20scale%20of%20the%20first%20operand%20plus%20the%20value%20of%20the%20div_precision_increment%20system%20variable%20(which%20is%204%20by%20default)).

But, I am not sure if Understood your original query thoroughly:

1. What does **WHERE 1** do?
2. Why do you count the **years** column and call it **numberofemployees** (why not simply do **count(*)**)